# error (cannot read properties of undefined (reading state)) add this.state.a in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I don’t understand why I have this error, I’ve never worked with class components, but I have a lot of experience with functional ones, I installed the application using create react app, maybe I’m missing some npm package for Es5

```
import React from "react";

import Tovars from './tovar'

export default class Tovar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            a:true
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <>
            {this.state.a}
            </>
        )     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value of `a` to a string, because a `boolean value` is not a valid React child. E.g, you want the *word* "true", not the *value* `true`

Your render method should look like this:

```
 render() { 
        return (
            <>
            {this.state.a.toString()}
            </>
        )     
    }
```

Comment: your dont undertand my answer

Comment: if i use useState then work my code of if i use this.state then not work

Comment: As the error message says: "cannot read properties of undefined (reading state" this indicates that your state is probably undefined when the component is first rendered. You could add a condition to guard the render so `if (!this.state) return null` etc. Otherwise I dont believe there is a difference between how class and function components would behave in this example